# Not getting what's happening in the C code below

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
  int arr[20],i,n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)      
  {           
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);      
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)      
  {           
    printf("%d",arr[i]);      
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In this block of code when I am inserting any character value the code breaks but normal integer can take character values as input

Comment: ugh...please format your code first.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
```

Please have a check to see whether `scanf()` passed or not

```
if(scanf("%d",&arr[i]) != 1)
{
  printf("scanf failed\n");
}
```

While scanning, the format specifier type should match with the parameter that is passed for scanning if this is not the case then it will lead to undefined behavior

Comment: Thanks Gopi yes the scanf is failed in this case 
int n='a';
printf("%d",n); 
This is running completely fine
So does that means that we can intialize int variable with char costant
but we cannot take  input of char constant into int variable using scanf?

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
     //Define a int Array with size 20, and two int Variables i and n
     int arr[20],i,n;
     //Read integer from Keyboard and save that value in n
     scanf("%d",&n);
     //Run this loop from 0 until the value you entered by Keyboard
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)      
     {
          //Read integer from Keyboard to array at index i
          scanf("%d",&arr[i]);      
     }
     //Run this loop from 0 until the value you entered by Keyboard (n)
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)      
     {           
          //Print integer at array index i to console
          printf("%d",arr[i]);
     }
    return 0;
}
```